# PHP call_user_func use reference on &$this

Tags: php, reference

what is the best way (memory safe) to use `call_user_func` from self instance eg.:

```
call_user_func(array($this, 'method'));
```

or by reference, eg.:

```
call_user_func(array(&$this, 'method'));
```

PS. i know the best way is `$this->method` but for framework design pattern reason (Wordpress) i do use `call_user_func`

Comment: That is a questionable design pattern. Yes, it is possible and does make sense in some very special cases. But in general it makes the code much harder to read (thus maintain) and breaks helpful auto completion and type hinting support by modern IDEs.

Comment: I would say it really depends on the situation and the complexity and what and how you want it to behave. I think (though I am not entirely sure) that both are quite safe since PHP handles all memory internally.

Comment: Generating your own explicit reference is more work for PHP as it now has to look after reference counts. PHP defaults to passing objects by reference anyway. It will only clone it if you modify it in your code. see [PHP copy on write means ok to pass large arrays by value if read only](http://webslainte.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/php-copy-on-write-means-ok-to-pass.html). The references in that article are quite interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am aware, it doesn't really matter, because PHP will do the same thing in both cases: will just [pass reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) to the same object (the object will be not cloned). So for simplicity, I would go without `&`

Some test:

```
class test 
{ 
    function foo() {
        call_user_func([$this, 'bar']); 
        call_user_func([&$this, 'bar']);
    } 
    private function bar() {
        echo spl_object_hash($this), PHP_EOL;
    }  
}
```

and outputs:

```
php > $obj = new test();
php > $obj->foo();
0000000025077e4a0000000075174bd2
0000000025077e4a0000000075174bd2
```

Comment: in case of different object, php clone the object?

Comment: It doesn't.

class test1 
{
 
     function foo(test1 $x) {
         call_user_func([$x, 'bar']); 
         call_user_func([&$x, 'bar']);
     } 
     private function bar() {
         echo spl_object_hash($this), PHP_EOL;
     }  
 }

php > $obj1 = new test1;
php > $obj2 = new test1;

php > $obj1->foo($obj1);
0000000025077e4d0000000075174bd2
0000000025077e4d0000000075174bd2

php > $obj2->foo($obj1);
0000000025077e4d0000000075174bd2
0000000025077e4d0000000075174bd2